# Is there a way to make Google Sheet chart in Google Slides have a transparent background?

Tags: google-sheets

In my Google Slide, I have linked to a chart from a Google Sheet, and I want it to have a transparent background.

In my Google Sheet, on the chart, I have the background set to "None", which makes the chart transparent in Google Sheet. However, this transparent background property does not transfer to the chart in Google Slides.

Is there any way to work around this, or is there another way to make the chart transparent in Google Slides?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you can do is set the background color to None which gives you a fully transparent background.

Comment: This should be the accepted answer, click background in the google slides toolbar and select Transparent. Perhaps this feature was added after the accepted answer was posted.

Comment: Yeah, this feature was unavailable at the time, but I just updated the accepted answer. Thank you both

Comment: Does this still work for others? Where is the option for background colour?

When I add a chart, I don't see an option for background colour. If I right-click the chart, I can click "Format options" which opens an option pane on the right. There's a "recolour" menu in there, but none of the colour schemes have a transparent background.

Comment: This is the right answer, but it's missing an important step—you have to set the background color *in the associated Sheet data*. So if you insert a new chart within a slide, you should have a  icon in the upper-right of that chart. Click that, then `Open Source` (which opens the associated Sheet). From there, right-click the table and select `Chart Style`. Set Background Color to `None` and make any other changes needed.

Answer (score 4):

I had the same question, and found some Google's Product Forums that this is not possible: https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!msg/sites/IIr76F7R2sM/KlAw1lCMDQAJ

For a workaround I'm making the background color of the chart the same as the slide.

Comment: definitely disappointing but thank you for the workaround

Comment: Since my original answer was posted, Google has now enabled transparent backgrounds on Sheets charts embedded in Slides using the background color "None" setting @socksxbirkenstocks had previously tried!

Comment: Thank you @Polyvinyl, I just updated to the accepted answer